# What to do in build.xml to add parameters in java command in the execution of the program?

Tags: netbeans, jar, build.xml

I can only execute an application i made, with the following command in the command line:

> java -jar -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true P2P_network.jar

I would like to know, how can i put this in the jar file, so i can execute it automatically, without needing to go to the command line.

The IDE used is netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880587/enabling-assertions-in-netbeans/1882739#1882739) may help.  The 'dash dee' and 'dash enableassertions' are both VM Options.