# Where to Enable the assertions

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-ee, jboss

I am developing a web application using Eclipse and the server is JBOSS 6.

I want to know how and where to enable the "assertion", so I can put assertions in my code, and there be the Assertion Errors while developing and testing.

I want to know if I have to do some configuration in Jboss, or some other place.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried , but googled it
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Enabling+assertions

Also look at this worked me for Netbeans 7.1
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18046315/2194456

And in jboss 7 , if you want to start in cmd line.
Go to bin folder of Jboss , then in standalone.conf file add
**JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -enableassertions"**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about JBoss, but if it has a place to put JRE arguments, you're looking for

`-enableassertions` and `-disableassertions`

Or you can use these on the command line

Check out http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html