# how to disable assertions in netbeans application development?

Tags: java, netbeans, assertions

I am working on a project using Netbeans Application development and there r errors caused due to assertions

i heard that assertions can be disable in jvm while running

can anyone tell how to disable assertions in netbeans application development

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880587/enabling-assertions-in-netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Based on what kind of assertions are used.

If it is the standard [Java assertions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html) introduced in 1.4.2, then simply remove the `-ea` (or `--enable-assertions`) VM argument of the run configuration.

Comment: in Netbeans Application development i

Comment: Then set the `-ea` VM option for the run configuration. First google hit I found: http://netbeanside61.blogspot.hu/2009/02/using-command-line-arguments-in.html

Comment: its Netbeans Application devolopment https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-paintapp.html